# In Rails 6 and FactoryGirl 4.9, how do I tie the original object back its has_many relation that's being created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-6, has-many

I’m using Rails 6 with FactoryGirl 4.9.0.  I have these models, one has a has_many with the other …

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
    …
  belongs_to :client

class Client < ApplicationRecord
    …
  has_many :contracts
```

In my factory, I have

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    name "Test Client”
  end

  factory :dp_client, class: Client do

    Contracts { [create(:contract)] }

  end
end
```

But when I go to use the factory,

```
create(:dp_client)
```

I get the error …

```
Validation failed: Client must exist
```

When creating the "has_many" relationship in jn my factory, I do I tie it back to the object that's creating it?

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/4-9-0-stable/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

Comment: The comment above is the solution. And if you have any problem with migrating FactoryGirl to FaactoryBot, you can check this one https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/4-9-0-stable/UPGRADE_FROM_FACTORY_GIRL.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :client do
    name { "Test client" }
  end

  factory :contract do
   client
  end

  factory :dp_client, class: Client do
    name { "client name" }
    after(:create) do |client|
      create(:contract, client: client)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's done like this:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :client do
    name { "Test client" }
  end

  factory :contract do
    association :client
  end

  factory :dp_client, class: Client do
    name { "Test DP Client"}
    contracts { [ FactoryBot.create(:contract) ]}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways to deal with this.

### Option 1:

Use the instance in your block. FactoryBot has `self` set to the factory and also passes it in as an argument. So both of these should work:

```rb
contracts { |factory| [build(:contract, client: factory.instance)] }

# or

contracts { [build(:contract, client: instance)] } # because self is the factory
```

Note: I use `build` here instead of `create` because of how Rails autosaves associations. Both should work fine in most use cases.

### Option 2: Use `after_create`

This is the solution that was proposed by Saiqul Haq. Main downside: It exclusively works for `create` (not for `build`). Also noteworthy: It might not reflect the reality of your app (e.g. if your records are always created together).

### Option 3: Use `before_create`

Similar to the previous solution, but potentially more realistic in terms of workflow:

```rb
before(:create) do |client|
  client.build_contract(attributes_for(:contract))
end
```

Comment: Your solution mentions "FactoryBot" but I'm using FactoryGirl.  Are they the same?  Anyway, with your option 1, I get the error, "undefined method `instance' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x00007ff47bcea730>" and option 2 gives the error "undefined method `factory' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x00007f8f32a83270>".

Comment: FactoryBot is the new name of FactoryGirl

Comment: Have you tried with the yielding syntax (= `contracts { |factory| ... }`)? One issue might be that your version doesn't support this approach yet (the last release of FactoryGirl is more than 4 years old => upgrade advised!).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in a position to change from FactoryGirl to something else.  I put the version that I'm using in the question title to help guide where I am.

Comment: From what I see, it should work with FactoryGirl 4.9.x as well. Also note that FactoryBot is directly compatible with FactoryGirl and all you need to do is replace the class name (e.g. `FactoryBot.define` instead of `FactoryGirl.define`). So in principle, your code should definitely work with FactoryBot 4.9.x and probably with anything below 5.0.0.